# How to manually emulate JS/Canvas globalCompositeOperation 'lighter'?

Tags: javascript, canvas, colors

If you blend two colors using a Canvas context object in e.g. Chrome, it will give richer colors (rather than averaging too much, which often becomes muddier). Given two rgba values in JavaScript, how would I be able to achieve this blending mode or something close to it 'manually'? (Without relying on specific browser implementations, and as it will be duplicated on the server-side, without the Canvas object.)

E.g.

```
var rgba1 = [255, 128, 0, 1];
var rgba2 = [0, 255, 255, 0.5];
var rgbaMix = this.mixRgbasLighter(rgba1, rgba2); // magic happens here
```

Thanks!

Comment: Check out this nice Blending shim by Phrogz:  https://github.com/Phrogz/context-blender

Comment: Looks very useful thanks! Will have to see if it supports varying transparencies for both rgb parts.